# SQL Query help getting monthly values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I have a query that basically sums a column for the current month based on a couple conditions.  I'd like to get each months values but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

```
DECLARE @d1 DATETIME = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()),0);
DECLARE @d2 DATETIME = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0);

SELECT    sum(SUMCOL)   as Total 
FROM COVERAGE
where

(COVERAGE_START_DATE>=@d1 and COVERAGE_START_DATE< @d2 and not PROCESSED_DATE>=@d2)   or

(COVERAGE_START_DATE< @d1 and PROCESSED_DATE>=@d1 and PROCESSED_DATE<@d2)
```

I was trying to just get the month

```
SELECT MONTH(PROCESSED_DATE)MONTH, sum(SUMCOL) as Total
```

and then group by month.........

```
GROUP BY  MONTH(COVERAGE_START_DATE)
```

but then realized that won't because I need to deal with the PROCESSED_DATE column too and couldn't get the additional logic down either.

Anyway, I would love some help on this.  Clearly SQL Queries aren't my thing :)  There has to be a way to this far more efficiently (and correctly) but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT MONTH(PROCESSD_DATE) AS MONTH, SUM(SUMCOL) AS Total
FROM COVERAGE
GROUP BY MONTH(PROCESSD_DATE)
HAVING ((COVERAGE_START_DATE BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2) AND PROCESSED_DATE <= @d2)
OR (COVERAGE_START_DATE < @d1 AND (PROCESSED_DATE BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2))
```

Comment: Using the above example, how do I fix --


 Column 'COV.Coverage_Start_Date' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

and



Column 'COV.Processed_Date' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Apologies as I'm just starting to learn some of this.